# Fortran weird behavior when writing a string

Tags: string, fortran, fastcgi

I am using fortran with `sqlite3` and `fcgi`.

I have the following allocatable string that is being passed to a subroutine:

```
    type(c_ptr)                       :: db
    integer                           :: rc
    type(c_ptr)                       :: stmt
    character(len=:), allocatable    :: json_o

    ! create database
    call create_db(db, rc)
    
    call get_all_lafi_json(db, rc, stmt, json_o)
    ! Printing works here
    Print*, json_o
```

This shows:

```
{"result":[]}
```

Now trying to use it in fcgi doesn't work at all.

Full code:

```
    use fcgi_protocol
    use sql_atlnts
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding 
    implicit none

    type(DICT_STRUCT), pointer  :: dict => null() ! Initialisation is important!
    logical                     :: stopped = .false. ! set to true in respond() to terminate program
    integer                     :: unitNo ! unit number  for a scratch file

    character(len=:), allocatable    :: json_o
    
    ! sql vars
    type(c_ptr)                       :: db
    integer                           :: rc
    type(c_ptr)                       :: stmt
    
    ! create database
    call create_db(db, rc)
    
    call get_all_lafi_json(db, rc, stmt, json_o)
    Print *, json_o 
    
    ! open scratch file
    open(newunit=unitNo, status='scratch')
    ! comment previous line AND uncomment next line for debugging;
    ! open(newunit=unitNo, file='fcgiout', status='unknown') ! file 'fcgiout' will show %REMARKS%

    ! wait for environment variables from webserver
    do while (fcgip_accept_environment_variables() >= 0)

        ! build dictionary from GET or POST data, environment variables
        call fcgip_make_dictionary( dict, unitNo )

        ! give dictionary to the user supplied routine
        ! routine writes the response to unitNo
        ! routine sets stopped to true to terminate program
        call respond(dict, unitNo, stopped)

        ! copy file unitNo to the webserver
        call fcgip_put_file( unitNo, 'application/json' )

        ! terminate?
        if (stopped) exit

    end do !  while (fcgip_accept_environment_variables() >= 0)

    ! before termination, it is good practice to close files that are open
    close(unitNo)

    ! webserver will return an error since this process will now terminate
    unitNo = fcgip_accept_environment_variables()


contains


    subroutine respond ( dict, unitNo, stopped)

        type(DICT_STRUCT), pointer        :: dict
        integer, intent(in)               :: unitNo
        logical, intent(out)              :: stopped
        
        ! the script name
        character(len=80)  :: scriptName
        

        ! retrieve script name (key=DOCUMENT_URI) from dictionary
        call cgi_get( dict, "DOCUMENT_URI", scriptName )
        select case (trim(scriptName))
            
            case('/api/v1/get_laf_items')
                write(unitNo, AFORMAT) json_o !Doesn't show anything in browser
                !Doing write(unitNo, AFORMAT) '{"results":[]}' works!
            
            case ('/api/v1/shutdown') ! to terminate program
                write(unitNo,AFORMAT) '{"shutdown":"true"}'
                stopped = .true.

        end select

        return

    end subroutine respond

end program atlnts_api
```

This `write(unitNo, AFORMAT) json_o` is not working. any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: What are `fcgi_protocol` and `sql_atlnts`? Is `AFORMAT` defined in one of these modules? And what happens if you replace the line `write(unitNo, AFORMAT) json_o` with `print *, json_o`?

Comment: Where do you expect `json_o` to get a new value?

Comment: What value does `AFORMAT` have?

Comment: `json_o` is getting passed in the subroutine  `get_all_lafi_json` and is changed there. `sql_atlnts` is a library I build than contains these handy sql functions. `fcgi_protocol` is one of the libraries of [FLIBS](http://flibs.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The file is running with a `spawn-fcgi` as `spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 ./api`